# Python: Compiling astropy with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, astropy

Currently I'm trying to compile a python application with pyinstaller for distribution. Unfortunately, the compiled version doesn't run, seemingly because of one of astropy's dependencies: six. Astropy encounters an import error on startup although I've even tried adding six to 'hidden imports' in the application's specs-file. Strangely however, during compilation pyinstaller notes that my hidden import 'six' has been found otherwise (this is also the only time six is mentioned) but still it doesn't show up in my distr directory after building.

Is this a known bug? I couldn't find any information related to using astropy/six with pyinstaller. Or is there a better solution perhaps?

Comment: astropy won't work quite out of the box with pyinstaller anyways--there are several other issues as well.  But I have gotten it to work.  See: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/960

Comment: I don't think this is terribly useful question to leave up on StackOverflow though, since you're not likely to get an answer.  It's a known open issue in Astropy.