# exe created with pyinstaller failed to execute

Tags: python, pyinstaller, astropy

I am trying to create an .exe file of my python script using pyinstaller. The exe file is successfully created but when I try to run it, cmd gives the error:

> **Import Error: Astropy requires the 'six' module of minimum version
>   1.10; normally this is bundled with the astropy package so if you get this warning consult the packager of your Astropy distribution. Failed
>   to execute script MARK1**

I have installed Astropy V1.33.

Comment: There are already multiple questions about this; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052982/python-compiling-astropy-with-pyinstaller

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known an ongoing issue with Astropy. Here is some discussion from the Astropy development on GitHub: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/960.

This question has also been asked a few times before:

- [Python: Compiling astropy with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052982/python-compiling-astropy-with-pyinstaller)
- [Missing "six" module for astropy after using cx_freeze/py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459120/missing-six-module-for-astropy-after-using-cx-freeze-py2exe) (issue with Astropy and py2exe, an alternative to pyinstaller)

You could try including six as a hidden-import in your pyinstaller settings. Otherwise, you might need to use a frozen version of Astropy, where they have added some edits to make it work with pyinstaller.

Comment: Glad for the response. But how to include six as a hidden-include in pyinstaller settings.

Comment: I tried using pyinstaller firstread.py [--hidden-import six] but it returns:                script 'C:\Python34\Scripts\[--hidden-import' not found

Comment: Oops, I meant hidden-import. Documentation is here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: It lists out so many modules, with cleanup and destroy tags. What now?

Comment: Sorry, if using the hidden-import approach didn't create a working .exe, then you might need to dig deeper (e.g. in the first link of my answer). Seems that the approaches are: (1) try with a different version of Astropy, (2) modify other Pyinstaller settings to get it to work with your current version of Astropy or (3) rewrite your project without using Astropy.

Comment: I've gotten Astropy to work fine with PyInstaller before but it requires some massaging, and a careful reading of the PyInstaller documentation and how to add the necessary hooks.  I wish I could share my earlier solutions but it was a long time ago.  The issue with the 'six' module is easily resolved, for example, if you ensure that 'six' is included in the bundle (it's a standard third-party Python module).

Comment: Yeah I was going through your discussion at github last night. Great to know that you got it worked. But, how do I ensure six is included and in which 'bundle'. Thanks.

Comment: I got it worked by excluding the astropy module and modifying my whole script, writing it without astropy.